# Get the related table values in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-3.0, foreign-key-relationship, has-many

i have 3 tables like A,B and C.. A and B has relation but A and C dont have any connection. B and C related.

In cakephp3 index action returns the A and B relation only .. i Need to take the table C data.

Table Details:

1. Purchase_details
2. measure_inventories
3. measurement_lables

[Table details image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EMH8.png)

Comment: Could you add your code to the question and have you looked at [Loading Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations)

Comment: added some more details.. hope it will be useful

Comment: where is your index action ?  post that function too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contain` to get associated table's data..

If you want association of association then you can use `recursive` too.
But if you want this only with one association then you can try this:

```
$data = $this->PurchaseDetails->find('all')
                    ->contain(['MeasurementInventories' => ['MeasurementLables']])->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use contain() to get associated table /model data like:-

```
$data = $this->PurchaseDetails->find()->contain(['MeasurementInventories' => ['MeasurementLables']])->toArray();
```

If your requirement is to show data only from measurement_lables then you can add select() to get your desired model data like:-

```
$data = $this->PurchaseDetails->find()->contain(['MeasurementInventories' => ['MeasurementLables']])->select(['MeasurementLables.*'])->toArray();
```

Note:- while using contain() you should be sure that the models are associated with each other. for example PurchaseDetails model should be associated with MeasurementInventories(belongsTo, hasMany, hasOne etc...)

```
$this->belongsTo('PurchaseDetails', [
    'className' => 'MeasurementInventories',
    'foreignKey' => 'columnName'            
]);
```

And MeasurementInventories is associated with MeasurementLables.

```
$this->belongsTo('MeasurementInventories', [
    'className' => 'MeasurementLables',
    'foreignKey' => 'columnName'            
]);
```